# I can't connect css, No mapping for GET /css/style.css

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot and I want to connect a css file, but the file does not work and gives a message in the console No mapping for GET /css/style.css.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ActHasForm</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"> 

</head>
<body>
```

```
I tried adding ResourceHandlerRegistry to my configuration but it didn't help

@SpringBootApplication
public class AtiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(AtiApplication.class, args);
    }
    
     @EnableWebMvc
     @Configuration 
     static class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
         @Autowired
         AtiServiceImpl atiservise;
     
     @Override
     public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
     registry.addFormatter(new RegulatoryActFormatter(atiservise)); 
     registry.addFormatter(new RegulatoryFormFormatter(atiservise));
     }
        
        /*
         * @Override
         * 
         * public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {                       registry
         * .addResourceHandler("/resources/**") .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); }
     */
 }
```

```
I also tried adding the <base href="/"/> tag to my html, but it didn't work either
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading http://localhost:8080/cont3xt/css/style.css. If the style.css page loads then th:href="@{/css/style.css}" must be changed to th:href="@{./css/style.css}" or th:href="@{css/style.css}".

Otherwise, try loading http://localhost:8080/cont3xt/static/css/style.css. If the style.css page loads then the static folder should be moved to the same level as resources.

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.static-content): contents of /static should be served statically by spring boot.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I moved the slyle.css to the static folder and the css file earned, but if it is in the css folder, it does not want to work, tell me why?that is, this is how static/style.css works, and there is static/css/style.css that stops working

Comment: static/style.css is not what I suggested. I don't know why it works